# What is the best approach to implement Time series forecasting to predict future customer orders?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, data-science

I have 2 years of historical data of customers, items ordered and the numbers of orders. Based  on this data, I am trying to predict the future sales at customer - item level. I tried ARIMA model which didn't give me the expected results. Any suggestions or references of implementation. I am interested to try LSTM and looking for good retail references.

Answer (score 0):

ARIMA models can be challenging to work with as there are a lot of parameters which need to be set in a reasonable manner, especially if you're trying to model seasonality.

Here's a decent starter discussion (with code) on using an LSTM for retail sales problem: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/

Also, consider working to identify some dependent variables which may impact sales to add as auxiliary inputs.  For example - some items could sell more during certain seasons, around national holidays, etc.

Forecasting at this detailed of a level is always challenging so the more variables you can find which explain the observed phenomena, the better you may be able to do.